# Ignore Empty files C#

Tags: c#, file

I am trying to avoid empty files in my Program and the way i am doing it doesnt work.

I got a machschine that create logs, at Weekend is nobody here and  but the maschine create a file  with only 5,6 lines, the right one should have 20k lines.

I know there is FileInfo.Length  but i dont know how to use it with this what a have right now.

```
public List<SystemLogFileData> ProcessSystemLogFiles(List<string> systemLogsFilePaths)
{
    List<SystemLogFileData> systemLogFilesData = new List<SystemLogFileData>();

    foreach (var filePath in systemLogsFilePaths)
    {
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
        var systemLogFileData = ProcessSystemLogFile(lines.ToList());

        if (File.ReadAllText(systemLogFileData).Length > 100)
        {
            systemLogFilesData.Add(systemLogFileData);
        }
    }

    return systemLogFilesData;
}
```

Comment: When you debug the code shown, which specific operation isn't doing what you expect?  What were the values used in that operation when the problem occurred?  What was the result you observed?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for FileInfo.Length? There's an example there... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.length?view=net-6.0

Comment: how is a file with 5-6 linies an empty file?

Answer (score -1):

I solved it and it works well. Not in my main Program but in Autobackup.

insted of ignoring the the not important file i don't copy them and i reached my goal.

Thakns for the help!

```
    //path of file
    string pathToOriginalFile = @"C:\Users\Desktop\c#\Logging\Systemlog.bk66";


    //duplicate file path 
    string PathForDuplicateFile = @"C:\\\Desktop\c#\Systemlog";

    //rename fileName if Exists
    FixFileName(ref PathForDuplicateFile, ".bk");

    if (File.ReadAllText(pathToOriginalFile).Length > 2000)
    {

        File.Copy(pathToOriginalFile, PathForDuplicateFile);

    }
      else
    {
      

    }
    //provide source and destination file paths
```